# Azure App Service - Does a new SSL Cert get automatically used?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

We have an Azure app service which has an SSL cert which expires in about 30 days - I have purchased and installed a new SSL cert which is shown in the Azure portal as Healthy with the right expiry date - the about to expire SSL cert is also shown with a warning of its impending expiration.

My question is does the new SSL Cert automatically take over when the old one expires - or do I need to something else - e.g. delete the old SSL

Thanks in advance for any help with this

Comment: If the below answer provided by AjayKumarGhose-MT was helpful ? If so could please accept the answer as solution.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, Check whether you have enabled Auto Renew Option if not, find the below steps to enable auto renew .

if Auto Renew is on then it will be renewed automatically before it expires, the linked App Service Apps will be moved to the new certificate.

For Auto Renew [App Service Certificate](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/internals-of-app-service-certificate/), you could check it in your App Service Certificate -> Auto Renew Settings -> Auto Renew App Service Certificate

below is the link to upload SSL certificate manually.

Or,

To upload your renewed certificate to your app service, also you can use this powershell command [New-AzureRmWebAppSSLBinding] (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.websites/New-AzureRmWebAppSSLBinding?view=azurermps-6.6.0).

Comment: Thank you for your response I have uploaded a renewed certificate but my question remains 'Does the new SSL Cert automatically take over when the old one expires - or do I need to something else - e.g. delete the old SSL'

Comment: Yes it will be automatically renewed if auto renew is enable, Else you would have to remove and upload the new SSL on the expire date.

Answer (score 0):

When the question 'Does my app service SSL cert get renewed automatically?' is asked the common response advises the questioner to check the 'Auto Renew' option. But when the SSL cert was purchased from a 3rd party and uploaded to the app service there is no 'Auto Renew' option available. This answer is to address that scenario.

The MS doc here gives details on what to do in an 'uploaded SSL' scenario.
[Renew Certificate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/app-service/configure-ssl-certificate?tabs=apex%2Cportal#renew-uploaded-certificate)

- Upload the new certificate to the app service via the TLS/SSL option
- Bind the new certificate to the same custom domain without deleting the existing, expiring certificate.

  Go to your App Service app's TLS/SSL settings pane, and select
  '+Add Binding'. This action replaces the binding, rather than remove    the existing certificate binding.
- You can now delete the existing, expiring certificate

You need to follow these steps because the app service bindings will not automatically update for any hosts when the certificate has been manually loaded in to an App Service Private PFX Certificates.